# how to check if a hash reference is empty in perl

Tags: perl

I need to test, whether my hashref contains 0 elements.
I used this code:

```
$self = { fld => 1 };
%h = ( "a" => "b" );
$self->{href} = { %h };
print STDERR $self->{href}{ "a" };
print STDERR "\n";
print "size of hash:  " . keys( %h ) . ".\n";
print "size of hashref:  " . keys( $self->{href} ) . ".\n";
```

It works well with perl 5.16, but fails with perl 5.10:

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not hash element) at - line 7, near "} ) "
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you'd use

```
%hash
```

for a hash, you'd use

```
%{ $hash }
```

for a reference, so it's

```
keys %{ $self->{href} }
```

Note: In some versions of Perl, `keys` accepts a reference. However, this was an experimental feature that was abandoned. One shouldn't use it.

Comment: If _ref_ is not a hash it's possible to do this `if (!keys $self->{'href'}) {}` in if statement. Is is gonna work the same in all Perl versions?

Comment: No. That was an experimental feature that was abandonned.

Comment: Does this return empty or 0?

Comment: @landesko, Don't ask new questions in the comment, especially not in the comments of an answer that has no relation to your question.

Comment: Are you serious @ikegami? Determining what the above expressions equate to goes along exactly with the spirit of the question.

Comment: @landesko, Quite serious. If you want to know what `keys` does, go read the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html). If after that you still need some clarification, [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Question is: **how to check if a hash reference is empty in perl.**

I ask: **Does this return empty or 0?** You could choose to be helpful and answer the question, and then suggest that this might not be the place for it, but instead would rather show your stack overflow prowess. Good job man! @ikegami

Comment: @landesko, Your question is unanswerable and in the wrong place. I gave you precise instructions on how to resolve your problem. Your unwillingness to listen doesn't make me unhelpful. Please stop spamming.

Comment: @ikegami Please elaborate why my question is unanswerable. In addition, if it is unanswerable, how would asking a question help?

Comment: @landesko, It's unclear what "it" is. // I presume you would be clearer in posting a Question. If not, we would request the additional information in comments to your question.

Comment: @ikegami, oh relax. @landesko: keys() is context-sensitive and will return either a list of keys or the number of keys, depending on whether it's evaluated in list or scalar context, respectively. So my @foo = keys(%bar) will get you a list, whereas my $baz = keys(%bar) will give you a number.  In the future, you can use `perldoc -f` to search builtins. :)

Comment: @Alaska, What about `%{ $hash }`?

Comment: @Alaska, It sounds like you are recommending `keys(%{ $ref })` to check if a hash is empty. Why wouldn't you just use `%{ $hash }` to check if a hash is empty? Oh, you know that there is a gotcha in older version of Perl? Why didn't you mention that? Why are pilling on OT comments? This is exactly the mess I was the rules and I were trying to avoid!

Answer (score 3):

To find out if a hash has elements, you just use it in scalar context:

```
scalar %h
```

or

```
%h ? "yup" : "nope"
```

`scalar keys %h` accomplishes the same purpose by counting the keys in `%h`, but it's better to ask for what you actually want to know.

Either way, however, `%h` is a hash and not a hashref.  (Though some versions of Perl do tolerate a hashref as an argument to `keys`.)  Given an expression `EXPR` that evaluates to a hashref, you get at the corresponding hash by saying `%{ EXPR }`.  Putting this together with your sample code, we get

```
print "size of hashref:  " . keys( %{ $self->{href} } ) . ".\n";
print "hash " . (%{ $self->{href} } ? "does" : "does not") . " contain elements\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Using references with builtin functions like `keys` is only supported in newer Perls. For maximum compatibility, you need to dereference it first:

```
print "size of hashref:  " . keys( %{ $self->{href} } ) . ".\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference it as a hash:

```
print "size of hashref: ", keys %{ $self->{href} }, "\n";
```

For the TIMTOWTDI, to check if it has any keys, you don't need `keys`:

```
print "undefined" unless %{ $self->{href} };
```

Comment: In the version of Perl he's using, that last snippet would needlessly iterate over the entire hash. Just fyi.